# Deriving the covariance of a $\text{MA}(\infty)$ representation of an $\text{AR}(1)$ process

Tags: time-series

My course notes have what I think can be paraphrased as follows. (Red sections are my interpolations.)

> Let \begin{align}
> y_t
> & =\alpha y_{t-1}+\epsilon_t \\
> & =\alpha(\alpha y_{t-2}+\epsilon_{t-1})+\epsilon_t \\
> & =\dots \\
> & =\alpha^ty_0+\sum_{i=0}^\infty\alpha^i\epsilon_{t-i} \\
> & \xrightarrow[|\alpha|<1]{t\rightarrow\infty}\sum_{i=0}^\infty\alpha^i\epsilon_{t-i}
> \end{align} with $\epsilon_t\sim\text{White Noise}(0,\sigma^2)$; then \begin{align}
> & \mathbb{E}(y_t)=\sum_{i=0}^\infty\alpha^i\mathbb{E}(\epsilon_{t-i})=0 \\
> \therefore \; & \begin{aligned}[t]
> \gamma_h
> & \;\color{red}{:= \text{Cov}(y_t,y_{t+h})} && (1) \\
> & \;\color{red}{=\mathbb{E}(y_ty_{t+h})-\mathbb{E}(y_t)\mathbb{E}(y_{t+h})}  && (2) \\
> & = \mathbb{E}(y_ty_{t+h})  && (3) \\
> & \;\color{red}{=\mathbb{E}\left(\left(\sum_{i=0}^\infty\alpha^i\epsilon_{t-i}\right)\left(\sum_{j=0}^\infty\alpha^j\epsilon_{t+h-j}\right)\right)}   && (4) \\
> & = \mathbb{E}\left(\sum_{i,j=0}^\infty \alpha^i\epsilon_{t-i}\alpha^j\epsilon_{t+h-j}\right) && (5) \\
> & = \sigma^2\sum_{i=0}^\infty\alpha^i\alpha^{i+h}  && (6) \\
> & = \frac{\sigma^2\alpha^h}{1-\alpha^2}.  && (7)
> \end{aligned}
> \end{align}

I get that $$\mathbb{E}(\epsilon_{t-i}\epsilon_{t+h-j})=\mathbb{V}(\epsilon_t)=\sigma^2$$ but I can't figure out how the $j$ is eliminated in step $(5)\rightarrow(6)$. Where did the terms involving $j\neq i+h$ go?

(See [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2416860/596895) answer for what I was expecting the 'missing' terms to look like.)

Comment: You missed the "$E$" operator since $(4)$.

Comment: @Zhanxiong Thanks. I noticed as you were typing your comment.

Comment: This is simply because $E(\epsilon_{t - i}\epsilon_{t + h - j}) = 0$ when $j \neq i + h$ (due to that $\{\epsilon_t\}$ is white noise).

Comment: @Zhanxiong I think that's what I was looking for. The comment is enough for me, but if you care to make that an answer I'll be happy to accept.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:**
\begin{align}
E(\epsilon_{t - i}\epsilon_{t + h - j}) = 0 \;\text{ if } j \neq i + h.
\end{align}