# Finding the variance of a differenced AR(1) process

Tags: time-series, self-study

I'm working on an unassessed course problem,

> If $y_t$ is the $\text{AR}(1)$ process $$y_t=\alpha_1y_{t-1}+\epsilon_t,$$ where $(\epsilon_t)$ is $\text{White Noise}(0,\sigma^2)$, and $|\alpha_1|<1$, find the covariance function of the differenced process $w_t=y_t-y_{t-1}$, and show that $\text{Var}(w_t)=2\sigma^2/(1+\alpha_1)$. Hence find the acf of $w_t$.

I think I need the variance first, and that will give me the covariance, and that will give me the acf. For the variance I get
\begin{align}
& \begin{aligned}
w_t
& = y_t-y_{t-1} && (1.1) \\
& = (\alpha_1y_{t-1}+\epsilon_t)-y_{t-1} && (1.2) \\
& = (\alpha_1-1)y_{t-1}+\epsilon_t && (1.3) \\
& = \dots \\
& = (\alpha_1-1)\alpha_1^{t-1}y_0+(\alpha_1-1)\sum_{i=0}^{t-2}\alpha_1^i\epsilon_{t-i} && (1.4) \\
& \xrightarrow[|\alpha_1|<1]{t\rightarrow\infty}(\alpha_1-1)\sum_{i=0}^\infty\alpha_1^i\epsilon_{t-i}  && (1.5)
\end{aligned} \\[1em]
\therefore \; & \begin{aligned}[t]
\mathbb{E}(w_t)
& = \mathbb{E}\left((\alpha_1-1)\sum_{i=0}^\infty\alpha_1^i\epsilon_{t-i}\right) && (2.1) \\
& = (\alpha_1-1)\sum_{i=0}^\infty\alpha_1^i\mathbb{E}(\epsilon_{t-i}) && (2.2) \\
& = 0 && (2.3)
\end{aligned} \\[1em]
\therefore \; & \begin{aligned}[t]
\mathbb{V}(w_t)
& = \mathbb{E}(w_t^2)-\mathbb{E}(w_t)^2 && (3.1) \\
& = \mathbb{E}\left(\left((\alpha_1-1)\sum_{i=0}^\infty\alpha_1^i\epsilon_{t-i}\right)^2\right) && (3.2) \\
& = (\alpha_1-1)^2\sum_{i=0}^\infty\alpha_1^{2i}\mathbb{V}(\epsilon_{t-i}) && (3.3) \\
& = (\alpha_1-1)^2\frac{\sigma^2}{1-\alpha_1^2} && (3.4)
\end{aligned}
\end{align}

and I can't figure out how this can equal $2\sigma^2/(1+\alpha_1)$. Could someone give me a pointer?

Comment: Do you know how to calculate the ACF of $\{y_t\}$?

Comment: @Zhanxiong My course notes have $$\rho_h=\text{Cor}(y_t,y_{t+h})=\frac{\text{Cov}(y_t,y_{t+h})}{\sqrt{\text{Var}(y_t)\text{Var}(t_{t+h})}}=\frac{\gamma_h}{\gamma_0},$$ so I figure the ACF comes after the variance and covariance.

Comment: Check whuber's answer.

Comment: @User1865345 I think it does (or would if I thought about it for a while). I've accepted Zhanxiong's answer, since it's specific to the details of my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\DeclareMathOperator{\Var}{Var}$
$\DeclareMathOperator{\Cov}{Cov}$

In [this answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/605223/deriving-the-covariance-of-a-textma-infty-representation-of-an-textar/605229#605229), you have already derived that the auto covariance function of $\{y_t\}$ is
\begin{align}
\gamma(h) = \frac{\sigma^2\alpha_1^h}{1 - \alpha_1^2}.
\end{align}

It then follows from the bilinearity of covariance (see [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/578792/285236) and [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/38722/285236)) that
\begin{align}
\Var(w_t) &= \Var(y_t - y_{t - 1}) \\
&= \Var(y_t) + \Var(y_{t - 1}) - 2\Cov(y_t, y_{t - 1}) \\
&= 2\gamma(0) - 2\gamma(1) \\
&= 2\sigma^2\frac{1 - \alpha_1}{1 - \alpha_1^2} \\
&= \frac{2\sigma^2}{1 + \alpha_1}.
\end{align}

Comment: We seem to be using terminology differently. Isn't $\gamma_h$ or $\gamma(h)$ the (auto?)covariance rather than the autocorrelation?

Comment: I checked the book, seems you're right.  I will correct it.

Comment: This covariance algebra is fairly new to me. Would you agree that the covariance function of $w_t$ is as follows? \begin{align}
\text{Cov}(w_t,w_{t+h})
& = \text{Cov}(y_t-y_{t-1},y_{t+h}-y_{t-1+h}) \\
& = \text{Cov}(y_t,y_{t+h}) - \text{Cov}(y_t,y_{t-1+h}) - \text{Cov}(y_{t-1},y_{t+h}) + \text{Cov}(y_{t-1},y_{t-1+h}) \\
& = \gamma_h - \gamma_{h-1} - \gamma_{h+1} + \gamma_h \\
& = \frac{\sigma^2(2\alpha_1^h-\alpha_1^{h-1}-\alpha_1^{h+1})}{1-\alpha_1^2}.
\end{align}

Comment: That's Correct.

Comment: That's a relief. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

An AR(1) has covariance
$\gamma(h) = C[y_t, y_{t-h}] = \alpha \gamma(h-1) = \alpha^h \gamma(0)$ and $\gamma(0)
= V[y_t] = \alpha^2\gamma(0) + \sigma^2$ so $\gamma(h) = \alpha^h\frac{\sigma^2}{1-\alpha^2}$.

$$
C[y_t - y_{t-1},y_{t-h} - y_{t-h-1}]
= \gamma(h) - \gamma(h+1) - \gamma(h-1) + \gamma(h)\\
= 2\gamma(h) - \gamma(h+1) - \gamma(h-1)
$$
so
$C[w_t, w_{t-h}] = (2\alpha^h-\alpha^{h+1} -\alpha^{\lvert h-1\rvert })\frac{\sigma^2}{1-\alpha^2}
$
and
$C[w_t, w_{t}] = 2\frac{\sigma^2}{1+\alpha}$.