# Variance of change after $K$ steps in AR(1) model

Tags: time-series, gaussian-process, autoregressive

I am generating from a standard AR(1) process. Lets assume a decay time lag $\tau=100$ and unit time steps of $\Delta t=1$, so $\phi=\exp(-1 / (\tau/\Delta t))=0.99$. The predicted autovariance is $\sigma^2 = \frac{1}{1 - \phi^2}$.

Then the AR is defined as $y_{i+1} = \phi \times y_i + \epsilon$, where $\epsilon \sim \mathrm{Normal}(0,1)$.

Now I want to investigate the change after K steps: $$y_{i+K}-y_i$$

I find empirically that the distribution is normal with variance:

$$\sigma(K)^2 = (\tau/2 + 1) \times (1 - \exp(K/\tau)^2)$$

Can this be derived analytically?

I suspect that K steps incur $\tau$ standard deviations of variance $\sigma^2$, but why half of that, and why the offset?

More generally for Gaussian processes: How can this variance be derived from the integral over the power spectral density?

This question is different from autocorrelation/autocovariance, which looks at $y_{i+K} \times y_i$.

---

Here is my python code:

```
import numpy as np
def generate_AR(N = 1000, sigma = 1.0, c=0, dt=1., tau=100):
    W = np.random.normal(0, sigma, size=N)

    # correlation: set to < 1, otherwise not stationary!
    phi = np.exp(-1. / (tau / dt))

    y = np.empty(N)
    y[0] = W[0]
    for i in range(1, N):
        y[i] = c + phi * y[i-1] + W[i]
    return y

tau = 100
for i, dN in enumerate([2, 4, 10, 40, 100]):
    dy = np.empty(10000)
    for i in range(10000):
        y = generate_AR(N=dN, tau=tau, dt=1)
        dy[i] = y[-1] - y[0]
    print('tau:', tau, 'steps:', (dN-1), 'variance:', np.var(dy))
```

Answer (score 2):

Just using the following two facts:

1. $\operatorname{Var}(y_{i + K} - y_i) = \operatorname{Var}(y_{i + K}) + \operatorname{Var}(y_i) - 2\operatorname{Cov}(y_{i + k}, y_i) = 
   2\gamma(0) - 2\gamma(K)$, where $\gamma(h)$ is the autocovariance function of $\{y_t\}$.
2. For an AR(1) process with white noise variance $\sigma^2$, its autocovariance function is [given by](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/605223/deriving-the-covariance-of-a-textma-infty-representation-of-an-textar/605229#605229):
   \begin{align}
   \gamma(h) = \frac{\sigma^2\phi^h}{1 - \phi^2}.
   \end{align}

In your case, $\sigma = 1$, hence $\operatorname{Var}(y_{i + K} - y_i) = 
2\gamma(0) - 2\gamma(K) = \frac{2(1 - \phi^K)}{1 - \phi^2}$.

Answer (score 0):

By repeated substitution, we obtain
$$
y_{i+K} = \phi y_{i+K-1} + \epsilon_{i+K} =  \phi^2 y_{i+K-2} + \phi \epsilon_{i+K-1} + \epsilon_{i+K} = \ldots
= \phi^K y_i + \sum_{j=0}^{K-1} \phi^j \epsilon_{i+K-j}
$$
We thus have
$$
\mathrm{Var}(y_{i+K}-y_i) = \mathrm{Var}\left((\phi^K -1) y_i + \sum_{j=0}^{K-1} \phi^j \epsilon_{i+K-j}\right)
$$
We know that $\mathrm{Var}(y_i)=\sigma^2$, $\mathrm{Var}(\epsilon_{i+K-j})=1$ for all $j$, and also that $y_i$ is uncorrelated with $\epsilon_{i+1},\ldots,\epsilon_{i+K}$. Putting everything together gives
$$
\mathrm{Var}(y_{i+K}-y_i) = (1-\phi^K)^2 \sigma^2 + \sum_{j=0}^{K-1} \phi^{2j} = (1-\phi^K)^2 \sigma^2 + \frac{1-\phi^{2K}}{1-\phi^2}
$$